# Go template to print an array's length

Tags: arrays, go, go-templates

I have no Go experience. I use a tool, Podman, which is written in Go, it documents its `--format` option as,

```
-f, --format string   Format the output to a Go template or json (default "json")
```

I can see what I want with,

```
podman inspect localhost/myimage --format "{{.RootFS.Layers.length}}"
```

But, if I want to get the count of how many elements there are what do I do? I've tried different fields with `.count` and `.length` and `.len`, but I always get,

```
can't evaluate field FieldName in type []digest.Digest
```

I've also tried invoking this as `{{len(RootFS.Layers)}}`. I'm just kind of brute forcing it. When I do the above, I get,

> ERRO[0000] Error printing inspect output: template: all inspect:1: unexpected "(" in operand

What is the right Go Template to get an array's element count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `go templating` language and syntax is different from the `go` language itself - so `len(RootFS.Layers)` as you have seen does not work.

From the [template docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions), you are using the correct function `len` but the template syntax does not require parenthesis. So use:

```
{{ len .RootFS.Layers }}
```

---

FYI: a quick [intro to Go templates](https://www.calhoun.io/intro-to-templates/).

Comment: You're not addressing the reason for confusion at all in this answer: you're just answering the question of syntax. The reason for confusion is because I assumed I needed to write Go Lang in a template (I looked up how to get an array's length in Go). A complete answer will address that it's not the case, that the syntax for a Go Template is different from Go(no parens), and that you can only call functions in the "global function map". Pointing out that you can add to it is great, but this is a step backward from a complete answer (and adding that isn't really apropos to the confusion).

Comment: Updated answer for clarity. The reason I bristled at the edit was that it suggested one is limited to just the global predefined functions. This is not the case. The go-template language is quite powerful. One can define their own functions, nested-templates, pipelines etc. to transform data in many reusable ways.